# EJS Template TypeError

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, web-applications, ejs

I am trying to learn more on Web Development, I'm stuck on EJS Template when I added the line

app.use("view engine", "ejs");

The server stopped running and now my web page doesn't connect.  I realise it's going to be hard to explain my issue here so I put my project upon Github here's the link https://github.com/OffalyPops/todolist-v1.git

I probably did something really stupid.  Feel free to download my project but leave easy to understand comments if you figure out what I have done wrong.

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nsDUG.png)

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Answer (score 0):

1. You are setting view engine, not using them, so should be `app.set` instead of `app.use`

```
// From:
app.use("view engine", "ejs");

// To:
app.set("view engine", "ejs");
```

2. The request route should be for client to get the content so it should be `app.get` instead of `app.set`

```
// From:
app.set("/", function(req, res) { ... }

// To:
app.get("/", function(req, res) { ... }
```

3. syntax error on else case in ejs, should be `{` instead of `(`

```
// From: 
<% } else ( %>n

// To:
<% } else { %>
```

Fixed error in your app.js

```
//jshint esversion:6

const express = require("express");
const date = require(__dirname + "/date.js");

const app = express();

// <!--LIST SETUP-->
const items = ["Jagger", "Vodka", "Beer"];
const workItems = [];

// <!--SETUP EJS TEMPLATE-->
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  let day = date.getDate();
  res.render("list", {listTitle: day, newListItems: items});
});

// <!--POST ITEMS ON DIFFENT LIST-->
app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const item = req.body.newItem;

  if (req.body.list === "Work") {
    workItems.push(item);
    res.redirect("/work");
  } else {
    items.push(item);
    res.redirect("/");
  }

});

app.get("/work", function(req, res){
  res.render("list", {listTitle: "Work List", newListItems: workItems});
});

app.get("/about", function(req, res){
  res.render("about");
});

app.post("/work", function(req, res){
  const item = req.body.newItem;
  workItems.push(item);
  res.redirect("/work");
})

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Serrer started on port 3000");
});
```

Comment: I edited all changes and still having problems.  I updated github also.

Comment: it seems like you have problem in app.js the comment should be `//` instead of `<!--` and missing `{`, updated answer above.

Comment: I started this project in Atom then I changed to inteliJ to see would same errors show up, they did.
I thought comments in html are <!--COMMENTS--> and in Java //COMMENTS,

Comment: html is <!--COMMENTS-->, JS is // or /*, app.js is a javascript file

Comment: I think the problem in the question is solved. Please accept the answer if you find it helpful.